# Incorrect Syntax: Create/Alter Procedure must be the first statement in a query batch

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This question has been asked before, but it all involved using "go" which I am not in need of here, at least I believe so.

I am following this tut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xMGwiV5A6o, near the 1:25 mark exactly. And his seems to execute while mine doesn't:

```
    Select * From Snacks

    Create Proc spGetSnackByID
    @Id int
    as

    Begin
    Select Id, Name, Location
    from Snacks where Id = @Id
    End
```

Here is the exact error, being highlighted with the "BEGIN" statement:

```
"Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spGetSnackByID, Line 7
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch."
```

Comment: Yes, SQL Server wants the create proc as the first line. Just remark out the select above, it is not what you want anyway, because you have specified the fields in the stored procedure.

Comment: Oh yes, that worked, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, SQL Server wants the create procedure as the first line. Just remark out the select above, it is not what you want anyway, because you have specified the fields in the stored procedure.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to keep the script as it is (select followed by a create procedure), you can construct the creation of the stored procedure in a `NVARCHAR` and `EXECUTE` it using `sp_executesql`. This way the CREATE statement is the *first statement*. Like this:

```
Select * From Snacks

EXECUTE sp_executesql N'
  Create Proc spGetSnackByID
  @Id int
  as
  Begin
    Select Id, Name, Location
    from Snacks where Id = @Id
  End
';
```