# Syntax error in sql server query

Tags: sql-server

I have written this code..

```
create procedure log_refresh_action
     (@p_obj_owner varchar(4000) = user, 
      @p_object varchar(4000),
      @q_new_object varchar(4000),
      @q_cur_object varchar(4000),
      @v_num_recs float,
      @v_start_date datetime,
      @v_comments varchar(4000) = 'NA') 
as
begin
    set nocount on;
```

I getting an error saying

> Incorrect Syntax near '4000'. Expecting '(', or SELECT.

Please help me with this issue

Comment: After I changed it displays an error message on create procedure saying 'CREATE PROCEDURE' must be the only statement in the batch

Comment: Execute like `EXEC sp_executesql N'/*create procedure ...*/'` (so place the whole create statement within the quotes).

Comment: @TT. can you please re write the code

Comment: You can see an example [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34775385/243373) I gave on a similar issue.

Comment: I have the same error occurring for create function where in it says 'CREATE FUNCTION' must be the only statement in the batch.

Comment: Do the same for the `create function ...` statement, wrap it in a call to `EXEC sp_executesql N' /*put your create function statement here*/ '`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have all these `CREATE ...` statements in a batch, place a `GO` in between each create statement (on a separate line).

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure, try like this

```
create procedure log_refresh_action
     (@p_obj_owner varchar(4000) = [user], 
      @p_object varchar(4000),
      @q_new_object varchar(4000),
      @q_cur_object varchar(4000),
      @v_num_recs float,
      @v_start_date datetime,
      @v_comments varchar(4000) = 'NA') 
as
begin
    set nocount on
end
```